# Trying to parse through a JSON to display images in app

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode

I believe I have narrowed down the problem to the fact that somewhere in the following code I am offering a conditional that should not be there. But for some reason when I run the app it gets as far down as the self.motorbikes line. With a Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error.

(Please see image)

[image]

Could it be the case that my DataSource.swift file is not connected to my motorbikes.json file?

I am trying to build this completely programmatically so not using storyboards is difficult for me. If anyone can help I would very much appreciate it.

```
import Foundation

class MotorbikeDataSource {

fileprivate var motorbikes: [Motorbike]?

init() {
    self.loadMotorbikes()
}

public func allMotorbikes() -> [Motorbike]? {
    return self.motorbikes
}

}

extension MotorbikeDataSource {

fileprivate func loadMotorbikes() {

    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "motorbikes", ofType: "json") else {
        assert(false, "Could not find motorbikes file")
        return
    }


    guard let contents = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) as Data? else {
        assert(false, "Could not load motorbikes file: \(path)")
        return
    }

    self.motorbikes = [Motorbike]()
    do {
        if let jsonDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: contents, options: []) as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
            if let motorbikes = jsonDict["motorbikes"] as? Array<Dictionary<String, Any>> {
                for motorbikeDict in motorbikes {
                    if let motorbike = Motorbike(dict: motorbikeDict) {
                        self.motorbikes?.append(motorbike)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        assert(false, "Could not parse motorbikes file: \(path)")
        return
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what is in logs? does it say something about nil?

Comment: and first thing you do with motorbikes is initialize it, just try to start it as a [Motorbike]()

Answer (score 0):

I have this sneaking suspicion that this is because the object is still in the initializer callstack. Maybe make the `loadMotorbikes()` func return the list of `Motorbike` objects and assign it in the initializer? An added bonus to doing it this was is that you can make the list of `Motorbike` objects a let constant.